# EsLint from Visual Studio - Unable to use static props on javascript files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint, ecmascript-next

Node Modules:

- EsLint 1.10.3
- Babel-EsLint 4.1.6
- Eslint-plugin-react 3.15.0

Sample file being linted:

```
class NotepadComponent extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'NotepadComponent'

    static defaultProps = {
        activeTab: 'type'
    }
}
```

Under the command line I can lint and transpile using babel without any issues. The problem is trying to lint from visual studio. I'm using the [Web Analyzer plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6edc26d4-47d8-4987-82ee-7c820d79be1d) which internally uses esLint.

This visual studio module defines a `.eslintrc` file under `C:\Users\My-Username` and I've gone ahead and updated this file, and the main folder for node_modules using this configuration:

```
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "classes":  true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jquery":  true
    },
```

But I still get the "JSX Parser: Unexpected Token =" error:

Any ideas on getting Web Analyzer to behave the same way the command-line tool does?

[image: Visual Studio Linting Error]

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Es6 for the defaultProps you have to set it outside the class, example:

```
class NotepadComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
}
NotepadComponent.defaultProps ={
                               activeTab:'type'
                               }
NotepadComponent.displayName = 'NotepadComponent'
```

Im not sure if it's that are you looking for, but maybe this help you

Comment: The static keyword is part of the ecmascript 2015 definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Answer (score 0):

I had a same kind of a problem in combination with TSLint and Web Analyzer. It turns out Web Analyzer uses its own node_modules installation in C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Temp\WebAnalyzer1.7.75. There you find also a nodeJS server(.js) that communicates the lint results to Visual Studio. I was able to adapt this server to get more error feedback in Visual Studio. This feedback told me that I should install missing npm packages in C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Temp\WebAnalyzer1.7.75. and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE. Maybe you can do the same for ESLint. See also [WebEssentials tslint custom rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518722/webessentials-tslint-custom-rules/36592153#36592153)